# How can I create user upload avatar function

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I am using nextjs and cloudinary-react in my project:

Here is my user info look like:
[image]

Here is my code base for upload function:

```
  const uploadImage = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", imageSelected);
    formData.append("upload_preset", "teammateme");

    axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/teammateme/image/upload", formData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };

return (     
<Card className="profile--card_container">
        <CardContent>
          {picture ? (
            <div>
              <Avatar
                src={picture}
                alt="Avatar"
                className="avatar--profile_image"
              />
              <input
                type="file"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  setImageSelected(event.target.files[0]);
                }}
              />
              <button onClick={uploadImage}>Submit</button>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <AccountCircleIcon className="avatar--profile_image" />
          )}
)
```

How can I make the upload image for user avatar?

Updated console:
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want? Send the image to server by api or update UI after api call success?

Comment: @agentp just update image of my console

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to get the `secure_url` returned upon a successful upload to Cloudinary. To achieve that, you can replace:

```
axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/teammateme/image/upload", formData)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

With:

```
axios.post("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/teammateme/image/upload", formData)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    var url = data.secure_url;
  });
```

That will log the full Cloudinary response and then extract the `secure_url` specifically in the `url` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do I need to create route in server to make it like send image from client to server and then store it on cloudinary?

Comment: In the current implementation, the upload is done from the client-side and that will store the image on Cloudinary. To keep the URL of the uploaded image on your server you will either have an endpoint on your server which you would pass the URL returned from Cloudinary and your user's identifier. Alternatively, you can pass the user's file for upload to your server and do the upload to Cloudinary on the server-side. This way, you can store the returned response from Cloudinary directly on your server and then you would pass to your front-end the URL to the newly uploaded image.

Comment: How can I write it?